# Fetch multiple APIs if a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm trying to fetch multiple URLs from the same API. I have an array of urls with the trending gifs, however, I want to push a new URL(with the searched gifs) only if the user clicks the search button. I'm kinda new in JS so let me know if there's something that doesn't make sense in the code

HTML

```
<body>
    <form>
        <label for="search">Search</label>
        <input id="search" type="search">
        <button id="btnSearch">Go</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

JS

```
function getAllUrls(urls) {
    try {
        let data = Promise.all(
            urls.map(url => fetch(url)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(content => {
                    console.log('[+]', content.data)
                    console.log('[-]', content.meta)
                })
            )
        )
        return data
    } catch (e) { console.log(e) };
}

function init() {
    let apiKey = 'xxxx';
    let urls = [
        `https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/trending?api_key=${apiKey}&limit=20&offset=3`,
    ]

    document.getElementById('btnSearch').onclick = function() {
        let userInput = document.getElementById('search').value.trim()
        let searchUrl = `https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${userInput}api_key=${apiKey}&limit=20&offset=5`
        return urls.push(searchUrl)
    }

    let responses = getAllUrls(urls)
}

init()
```

Problem:
Basically, the fetch function only returns the data of the trending gifs. I mean, even if I clicked the search button, the function only retrieves the trending gifs

Comment: You should describe the issue you're having with the current code and what you've tried.

Comment: What isn't working as expected?  What's the specific problem you've encountered?

Comment: The default type of a `<button>` is `submit`. A `<form>` without an `action="..."` attribute acts like a `<form>` with `action="<the site it's on>"`. If I click on the "Go" button it will submit the form to "itself" and therefor reload the site.

Comment: shouldn't `data` be returned in a `then` statement? `Promise.all(promisesArray).then( values => { return data; });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button would sumbit the form and hence refresh the page. Try setting to type button or preventing default actions.

```
<button id="btnSearch" type="button">Go</button>
<!-- or prevent default form submission -->
```

Also it doesn't seem you are *awaiting* the `Promise.all()` which returns a promise as well. Try refactoring that function to this:

```
function getAllUrls(urls) {
  return Promise.all(urls.map(url => fetch(url))).then(async (res) => {
    const data = await Promise.all(res.map(r => r.json()))
    data.forEach(d => {
      console.log('[+]', content.data)
      console.log('[-]', content.meta)
    })
    return data
  })
}
```

---

Try moving the getAllURLs function in button click event:

```
function init() {
  let apiKey = 'xxxx';
  let urls = [`https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/trending?api_key=${apiKey}&limit=20&offset=3`]

  document.getElementById('btnSearch').onclick = async function() {
      let userInput = document.getElementById('search').value.trim()
      let searchUrl = `https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${userInput}api_key=${apiKey}&limit=20&offset=5`
      urls.push(searchUrl)
      const responses = await getAllUrls(urls)
  }
}
```

Comment: Still only  returns the data of trending gifs if I cliked the search button

Comment: It's working, however, what if I want the trending gifs to be static?. I mean, when the user enters they have to see the trending gifs and If they search a gif the URL is added to the fetch function

Comment: @Nataly you can make a `fetch` request right after page load containing trending URL only.

Comment: Like a double fetch?

Comment: @Nataly 1 fetch on page load with trending URL. Another fetch on button click with search URL.

Comment: Cool, got it. Thanks